# Why is the Firefox debugger tab stopping network calls?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, leaflet

I am creating an application with Angular, Leaflet, ui-Leaflet and ag-Grid.  Of this I am not sure which one, if any, is contributing to this issue.  But today I found that, when refreshed, if the debugger is open, Firefox will not load the map on the home page.  This was happening using a local stand alone server (on localhost port 8000, or something).  I was wondering why, or more practically how, one might fix such an issue?

Comment: Check your debugger settings, you might have disabled something while debugger tools are open

Comment: Thanks @Arijoon but I checked that, no dice.